# How to write data to FS, HDFS or S3 by Flink File Sink with full permissions

Tags: scala, io, hdfs, apache-flink

I have a pipeline with Flink 13 and Kafka to HDFS (or FS). To write String files to HDFS I use File Sink (Row-encoded Formats) and created files don't have full permissions

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 flink flink 1545571 Oct  4 07:08 part-a8a42755-2d30-4b16-a93c-b9407764980f-1
-rw-r--r-- 1 flink flink 1545182 Oct  4 07:09 part-a8a42755-2d30-4b16-a93c-b9407764980f-2
```

Could you help me please to tune Flink file sink to write files to FS, HDFS or S3 storage with managed permissions, for example

```
drwxrwxrwx
```

Code

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SimpleStringEncoder
import org.apache.flink.core.fs.Path
import org.apache.flink.connector.file.sink.FileSink
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.rollingpolicies.DefaultRollingPolicy

val input: DataStream[String] = ...

val sink: FileSink[String] = FileSink
    .forRowFormat(new Path(outputPath), new SimpleStringEncoder[String]("UTF-8"))
    .withRollingPolicy(
        DefaultRollingPolicy.builder()
            .withRolloverInterval(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(15))
            .withInactivityInterval(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5))
            .withMaxPartSize(1024 * 1024 * 1024)
            .build())
    .build()

input.sinkTo(sink)
```

Code from docs
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/connectors/datastream/file_sink/#row-encoded-formats

Making the parent directory on job manager have full permissions did not help

```
drwxrwxrwt   1 root root 4096 Oct  4 18:38 tmp
drwxrwxrwx 1 root  root  4096 Oct  4 18:38 flink-output
drwxrwxrwx 1 flink flink 4096 Oct  4 18:47 2021-10-04--18
-rw-r--r-- 1 flink flink 1557542 Oct  4 18:48 part-87dfe0af-87b1-4a6d-b244-7329b5c567db-9
```

Comment: Make the parent directory have full permissions before running the program